# QGIS over WatchGuard Mobile VPN with SSL

Tags: qgis

something quite strange occured today. I connected to my office through WatchGuard Mobile VPN with SSL enabled. I got loads of errors about SSL certificates, WMS errors (there were WMS layers in the QGIS project file) and eventually, QGIS 2.01 crashed.

I got some colleagues to connect via VPN from one of our other offices and the same happend. QGIS is installed on my work laptop and this happens when I try to open figures on our network servers via VPN. When I am in the office, with the same laptop and same QGIS installation, and I try to open the same file, these errors do not occur. Therefore the problem is somewhere in the VPN connection. Why would QGIS fall over the VPN connection?

Thanks
Antonio

Comment: open the same file (what format?) Do you use a postgis database with the VPN?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "QGIS project file" with "same file". Also no postgis server. Only WMS and Shapefile layers in the QGIS project file.

Comment: OK this is now sorted. It took me two days to understand that it was a dodgy installation that went wrong. Basically, after uninstalling and installing various OSGeo4W and QGIS versions (32 and 64 bit) I realised that by deleting the keys in the Registry I finally managed to get a proper installation working. Now I can connect via VPN again.

Comment: Further update. I thought I had resolved only to find out that actually, when I install 64 bit versions, the problem arises again. As soon as I revert to 32 bit, the problem disappears. It would seem to me that the 64 bit installer is affected by SLL issues and also problems with paths when calling GRASS modules. These problems do not exist on the 32 bit versions it would appear.